# Installation CakePHP on Debian

Tags: cakephp, debian

Today I installed cakephp 2.4.2 on my debian server with ISP panel. When I open index.php file, i see this:

> Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 325
>
> Warning: /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 386
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:181
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_')
>   #1 /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/app/Config/core.php(367): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array)
>   #2 /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/var/www/use...')
>   #3 /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(177): Configure::bootstrap(true)
>   #4 /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/app/webroot/index.php(96): include('/var/www/use...')
>   #5 /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/index.php(43): require('/var/www/use...')
>   #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 181

How I can resolve this problem? (I already know about `chmod` on app/tmp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pretty much sums it up:

> Warning: /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable

Make sure that folder exists and is writable by your webserver user (usually `www-data` on Debian systems).